# How to post a photo to friend's wall (timeline) using Facebook IOS SDK dialog?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

How to post a photo to friend's wall like when you post a photo using facebook site (using "Post" form at the top of friend's wall and switched to "Photo" tab). Result should be something like this:
[image: result]

I know how to post a simple post to friend's wall using `[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession..]` and `@"to"` parameter. But is there any way to post exactly a photo (with big thumbnail)?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API
We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a friend's wall lead to a high incidence of user dissatisfaction (hiding content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be allowed. Please use the [Feed Dialog for posting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

```
// only supports passing a single image
NSArray* images = @[
@{@"url": [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-awesome-meal-photo.jpg"], @"user_generated" : @"true" }
];

id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html"   forKey:@"meal"];
[action setObject:images forKey:@"image"];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                  actionType:@"fbsdktoolkit:cook"
                         previewPropertyName:@"meal"
                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results,    NSError *error) {
                                         if(error) {
                                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                         } else {
                                             NSLog(@"Success!");
                                         }
                                     }];
```

Comment: I can post to friend's wall using `[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession..]`. See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). I wrote about it.

Comment: here is link to [post via feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#feeddialog)

Comment: Can you tell the setting of app for same. When I use this code post button is in grey color. How should i do?

Comment: @python whats in grey color ? facebook share  dialog does not open or something else. please clear your question. better will be post a screen shot .